# R-tree indexing in Postgresql 9.3

Tags: database, postgresql, r-tree

How can I use gist in Postgres to fast query a two dimensional geographic data in double precision?
For example, I have a table Points, which has three fields: point_id, X and Y and I want to use Postgres to quickly query point for which a < x < b and c < y < d. A detailed answer would be appreciated.

Comment: `CREATE INDEX name ON table USING rtree (column);` where `column` corresponds to your `Point` column.

Comment: This is not supported by new version any more

Comment: Why do you think an rtree index would be better? What is the problem with the current query you have?

Comment: People here might be able to much better help you when you post your table and index definitions, the query you are performing and the explain analyze output for that query.

Answer (score 0):

It is already implemented in PostgreSQL. You do not need to implement it, just create an appropriate index (look at GiST).